# How to proceed with the following dual optimization question

Tags: machine-learning, self-study, optimization, svm

So, here is an image of the question:
[image]

We are being taught binary classification currently, but I am not sure how to even use this in my objective /cost function. Even if I did, how would I take derivatives/gradients, because the max function would be present ? Clarification and help regarding this will be appreciated.

Comment: Hi, there are blind and visually impaired users of this 
site who interact with it using screen readers. The screen 
readers can't handle the equation in your screenshot. 
Please edit the post to include the equation as LaTeX. If 
it helps, we have some 
[resources on using LaTeX on Cross Validated](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1605/155836).

Comment: this looks like homework help, and could use that tag.

Comment: Cross-posted: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/148849/755, https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/562547/2921.  Please don't cross-post.